# Unable to Mount hard disk? sdb1/sdb2 not showing?

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs

I want to connect to ext hard disk and I m worried if I did some things and the data is lost.

When I do `lsblk` I get the following output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0   931G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk
```

Here sda is my internal hard disk and sdb is my external hard disk. Ideally, it should have been

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0   931G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sbd1   8:1    0    90G  0 part 
└─sbd2   8:2    0   431G  0 part
```

But this is show as disk not as partition. Because of this, I am not unable to read any data in this. Here are the few things I tried:

1. Connected to windows machiene, it gets connected but won't show on `This PC`
2. Did ntfsfix, doesn't work. Shows `NTFS signature is missing`

I do not know what else to do. Can someone experienced please guide me?

Comment: Check `/var/log/kernlog` for messages related to sdb, it will show what was recognized by system. But it looks like something went wrong before

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your disk is not partitioned.

If your disk contains valuable data, first make a backup image of it using dd (-> [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd)). Your command would be something like `dd if=/dev/sdb of=/image/path bs=1M`
Ensure that the media where you write the image has enough space (500GB apparently in your case).

Then, try opening it with gparted (graphical), parted (cli), gdisk or any other patitioning tool.

These tools will analyse your disk and tell you if they detect an error.

Rodsbook gives some good explanations [here](http://rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html) with gdisk :

```
# gdisk /dev/sdc
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.7.2

Warning! Main partition table CRC mismatch! Loaded backup partition table
instead of main partition table!

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************
```

You can then use the 'r' command (r for recovery) and ask for a verification 'v'. Follow then any recommandation given by gdisk.
Always use 'w' (write) before exiting, unless, of course, you want to discard your modifications.